# Lemmatizing German Texts with Textblob-de

Tags: python, lemmatization, textblob

Textblob-de is the German extension of Textblob and is documented under https://textblob-de.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

I want to lemmatize German words like hast -> haben, Häuser -> Haus with Textblob-de

I found this post from J. Schneider about different lemmatization methods in Python, which is tailored for English, which also includes a part about Textblob (English version): https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/lemmatization-examples-python/

I wonder if there is the possibility of doing lemmatization in the German extension too.

Following the text from J. Schneider the lemmatization should be possible with the following lines

```
from textblob_de import TextBlobDE, Word
word = 'hast Häuser'
w = Word(word)
w.lemmatize()
```

I receive the following NotImplementedError:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-16cfb68c1c58> in <module>
      2 word = 'hast Häuser'
      3 w = Word(word)
----> 4 w.lemmatize()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/decorators.py in decorated(*args, **kwargs)
     33     def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
     34         try:
---> 35             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     36         except LookupError as err:
     37             print(err)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob_de/blob.py in lemmatize(self, pos)
    161         #lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
    162         # return lemmatizer.lemmatize(self.string, pos)
--> 163         raise NotImplementedError
    164 
    165     @cached_property

NotImplementedError:
```

I expect output like:

```
haben Haus
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
from textblob_de import TextBlobDE

word = 'hast Häuser'
w = TextBlobDE(word)
print(w.words.lemmatize())
```

output:

```
['hast', 'Häuser']
```

For more information related to German language support for `TextBlob`, kindly check [this](https://pypi.org/project/textblob-de/).